# Rotate a Two.js object in its position

Tags: javascript, css, two.js

I have a large circle with smaller ones inside made using [two.js](http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/).

[image: greninja-aegislash-goodra]

My problem is that these two do not rotate in their own place but in the top left axis.
**I want the group of circles (`circlesGroup`) rotate only inside the large one in a static position**. The `circlesGroup` and the large circle are grouped together as `rotatoGroup`.

```
two.bind('update', function(frameCount, timeDelta) {
  circlesGroup.rotation = frameCount / 120;
});

two.bind('update', function(frameCount, timeDelta) {
  rotatoGroup.rotation = frameCount / 60;
});
```

The whole code is in [CodePen](http://cdpn.io/DaEhg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All visible shapes when invoked with `two.make...` ( circles, rectangles, polygons, and lines ) are oriented in the center like this Adobe Illustrator example:

[image: A circle with its origin at the center of the circle]

When this shape's `translation`, `rotation`, or `scale` change those changes will be reflected as transformations about the center of the shape.

`Two.Group`s however do not behave this way. Think of them as display-less rectangles. They're origin, i.e `group.translation` vector, always begins at (0, 0). In your case you can deal with this by **normalizing** the `translation` your defining on all your circles.

#### Example 1: Predefined in normalized space

In this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woDzk) example we're defining the position of all the circles around -100, 100, effectively half the radius in both positive-and-negative x-and-y directions. Once we've defined the circles within these constraints we can move the whole group with `group.translation.set` to place it in the center of the screen. Now when the circles rotate they are *perceived* as rotating around themselves.

#### Example 2: Normalizing after the fact

In this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKrEd) example we're working with what we already have. A `Two.Group` that contains all of our shapes ( the bigger circle as well as the array of the smaller circles ). By using the method `group.center();` ( line 31 ) we can normalize the children of the group to be around (0, 0). We can then change the `translation` of the group in order to be in the desired position.

*N.B: This example is a bit complicated because it invokes underscore's `defer` method which forces the centering of the group after all the changes have been registered. I'm in the process of fixing this.*

Comment: the code pen's code got this error on javascript's console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Two is not defined 
 at pen.js:-13"

Comment: Updated the pens with the latest Two.js. Works now and thanks for responding.